# Поиск по WebBrowser с повторным поиском  в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Я догадываюсь, что многим уже надоел вопрос связанный с поиском по `WebBrowser`! Но ответа по конкретному вопросу я не нашла!
Суть вот в чем: обычный поиск - ввод в `Edit` и при нажатии осуществляется поиск по тексту и при наличии слова, выделяется соответствующим цветом! 
Вопрос: как осуществить поиск так, чтобы после того как было найдено слово, он остановился, а при повторном нажатии на кнопку опять возобновился и показал следующее похожее слово и т.д.

```
procedure TOsnovForm.SearchAndHighlightText(aText: string);
var
  tr: IHTMLTxtRange;
begin
  if not WebBrowser1.Busy then
  begin
    tr := ((WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).body as IHTMLBodyElement).createTextRange;

    while tr.findText(aText, 1, 0) do
    begin
      tr.pasteHTML('<span style="background-color: Lime; font-weight: bolder;">' +
        tr.htmlText + '</span>');

      tr.scrollIntoView(True);

    end;
  end;
end;
```

Соответственно при нажатии на кнопку вызывается данная процедура

Заранее спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Поиск в Яндексе занял 2 секунды

```
procedure WBFindText(Browser:
TWebBrowser; const Direction: Boolean;
const FText: String;   const
SearchScope, Flags: Integer); var  
Doc: IHTMLDocument2;   SelObj:
IHTMLSelectionObject;   SelRange:
IHtmlTxtRange;
 begin
Doc := Browser.Document as IHTMLDocument2; 
 SelObj :=Doc.Selection;  
SelRange :=SelObj.CreateRange as IHTMLTxtRange;

  SelRange.Collapse(Direction);

  if SelRange.FindText(FText, SearchScope, Flags) then   begin
    SelRange.Select;
    SelRange.ScrollIntoView(True);   end
    else MessageBox(Handle, 'По Вашему запросу ничего не найдено', 'Поиск
 текста', MB_ICONINFORMATION);

end;
```

Использование:

**WBFindText(MyCoolBrowser, False, 'MyCoolText', 1, 0); //** Найти вперед

**WBFindText(MyCoolBrowser, False, 'MyCoolText', 1, 0 or 4); //** Найти вперед + чуствительность к регистру

**WBFindText(MyCoolBrowser, True, 'MyCoolText', - 1, 1); //** Найти назад

**WBFindText(MyCoolBrowser, True, 'MyCoolText', - 1, 1 or 4); //** Найти назад + чуствительность к регистру

Comment: ты хоть заметил какой это язык программирования??? 2 секунды...

Comment: Delphi, родной для меня язык.
Что тебе не понятно в приведенном коде?

Comment: ни спасибо от девушки ни извинений) маруся